# Есть ли проверочное слово к слову "необъятны''?

Tags: орфография, однокоренные-слова, орфоэпия

Не могу найти проверочного слова к слову «**необъятны**».

Comment: А какую букву Вы хотите проверить в этом слове?

Comment: А какие варианты, elena, есть у вас?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет орфограммы "безударный гласный корня" -он под ударением.

Что хотите проверить? Слитное написание?-без НЕ не употребляется

Твёрдый знак?-после приставки на согласный перед Е,Ё,Ю,Я пишется Ъ

Comment: Да, если речь  о приставке ОБ-, то она неизменяемая, приставки АБ не бывает

Answer (score 0):

Это словарное слово. Его надо запомнить.

Comment: А если бы слова _необъятный_ в словаре не было бы,  смогли бы Вы его написать по-другому?

Comment: Если изловчиться, можно написать с мягким знаком; проверочное слово: (из) Приобья :)

Comment: Слава, что Вы имеете в виду под "по-другому"?

Comment: _Серж: что Вы имеете в виду под "по-другому"?_ ===  Из сравнения со словами _разъять, изъять_ видно, что корень в _объять_ -- "я", приставка -- "об". По правилам после приставки на согласный перед йотированной гласной ставится твёрдый знак. Приставок "ни" не бывает, есть только "не". Проблемных букв в слове  «необъятны» не вижу и потому не уверен в том, что это слово можно относить к "словарным". Может, и ошибаюсь...

Comment: Слава, а Вы сможете подобрать такое родственное слово, где ***о*** будет под ударением?

Comment: _...где **о** будет под ударением?_ === См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=30#pp30 :

§ 33. Общее правило. Написание букв на месте безударных гласных устанавливается путем проверки **другими словами** и формами, где в той же значимой части слова (в том же корне, в той же приставке, суффиксе, окончании) проверяемый гласный находится под ударением… === Приставку "об" под ударением можно встретить, к примеру, в таких словах, как _обнял, обыгрыш…_ Ни одного слова с приставкой "аб" я не знаю. А Вы?

Comment: Впрочем, может и _словарное._ Я выше был не прав, когда сказал, что приставок "ни" не бывает. Бывают слова и с "ни". Обосновать же с помощью **правил**, почему в слове _необъятный_ нужно именно "не", а не "ни", я, пожалуй, не смогу.

Comment: Слава, да, про эти слова  я знаю. Но, наверное, слова «необъятны» и «обнять» не однокоренные. Этим и объясняется, что это слово словарное.

Comment: Т.Ф. Ефремова Новый словарь Русского языка. Обнять — обхватить кого-л. руками для выражения ласки; заключить в объятия, и в переносном смысле (охватить умом; постичь) — тоже значит Объять. Но это не так важно, как проверить другими словами и формами безударную О. Приставка «об», как укороченное от «оба, обе, обо» числительное, в этих словах играет роль второго корня. Как в «обоюдном, обозримом».

Comment: Во всех приведенных Вами примерах о безударное. Приставкой о в этом слове не проверяют.